# How to pass a get parameter into an ajax url

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i have been trying to fix this problem for a while and i am hoping that someone can help.
I want to pass an id from a php page to be included in the url of an ajax call.
See what i mean

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/app/data-(ID)",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var date = [];
            var value = [];
```

From the php page

```
$parameter = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$ID  = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Is it possible. If not how can a parameter from mysql database be included in an ajax url. Thanks inadvance

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. It _might be_ that you want to output that javascript code by means of php, if so, then you can treat it as plain text and list "echo" the ID into it. Or you could place the ID inside the HTML tree of some page you send out and then read it on the client side by means of javascript.

Comment: What i want to do is to pass an id from the php page to the javascript page.

Comment: Both my suggestions do that.

Comment: You just need to echo it in

Comment: Looking at the 2nd option how do i send it out and then read it on the javascript page. I tried to echo it but its giving a 403 forbidden error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your php page you can have a 'script' html element, where you can do something like this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/app/data-<?php echo $ID?>",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var date = [];
            var value = [];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Initially i separated the javascript file and the php file, included the javascript file on the php page and was trying to send the value of variable from the php page to the javascript page. But i copied the contents of the javascript onto the page and echo the ID. And it worked.

Comment: Awesome! Please mark my answer as the solution if possible!

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing javascript in a php file is generally considered bad practice, but if you really need to, you can use `echo` inside your php file to concatenate your `$ID` to the url value of the ajax call:

**page.php**

```
<?php

echo " $(document).ready(function(){ " .
     "      $.ajax({ " .
     "          url: 'http://localhost/app/data-" . $ID . "'," .
     "          method: 'GET', " .  
     "          success: function(data) { " . 
     "              console.log(data); " . 
     "              var date = []; " . 
     "              var value = [];" ;
?>
```

Note the example above won't run correctly, as it is only a portion of the JavaScript.